# jquery mobile page indicator (dots)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add page indicator in the bottom of my mobile web app
for example: if i'm in page 3 it should show me:

[image]

anyone know how to do it?

I found this: http://www.sunarlim.com/2013/05/jquery-cycle-pager-style/, but how can I make 10 dos it the same line?

Thank u,
Mor

Comment: Have you tried doing it and got stuck? `$(".ui-page").length` will give you number of pages in DOM. The rest is a css job.

Comment: Try buttons css side-by-side with iconpos notext and overwrite the icon css to show ony the background without icon. As @Omar says, css job

Comment: @frequent this gave me an idea of creating another navbar widget, different than the current one. Since the current navbar widget is being refactored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question shows no signs of effort, it is interesting.

*The below solution works for static pages, if you intend to add pages dynamically, then you have to add navigation links dynamically as well.*

### Solution 1

#### Static navigation bar:

Add navigation bar to **footer** div of each page. Add class `activePage` to link matching the current page.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <span class="ui-title"> <!-- to have the div centered in footer -->
    <div id="navigator">
      <a href="#p1" class="activeSlide">1</a>
      <a href="#p2">2</a>
      <a href="#p3">3</a>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DGeys/)**

---

### Solution 2

#### Dynamic navigation bar:

Here, you it uses the `.index()` of active page and it adds `activePage` class to link mathcing the page's index using `.eq()`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "[data-role=page]", function () {
    var active = "#" + $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
    var active_index = $(active).index();
    $(".activePage").removeClass("activePage");
    $("#navigator a", this).eq(active_index).addClass("activePage");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/STcVL/)**

---

#### CSS

```
#navigator {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 14px;
    z-index: 999;
}
#navigator a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #707173;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#navigator a {
    background: #00ffff;
}
#navigator a.activePage {
    background: #ff8000;
}
```