# How to design swipe page navigation?

Tags: jquery-mobile

We want to use several pages with horizontal transitions that will be triggered with swipe events. I guess this is quiet common, but what I could not find is a good way to indicate to the user, that there is another page which can be reached with a right swipe. So my questions are:

1) Is there a JQuery Mobile demo somewhere with a good solution to this? It wouldn't be elegant to spell out "swipe right to see contacts" to the user.

2) I think the Windows Phone Panoramas solve this nicely by showing a little bit of the other page on the right edge of the screen. That wastes some space but makes it intuitively clear that you must scroll to the right somehow to see more. Is this doable with jQM?

Comment: What about showing a dot for each page at the bottom of the screen like on the iPhone. The dot for the current page is highlighted so you know where you are. I think they are sometimes called pagination dots.

Comment: @ezanker: Yes, like in some image galleries. Not as intuitive as the Windows Phone solution but a lot less effort. I just want to make sure it is understood on as many devices as possible, because my experience is that users often do not know about the swipe. With the dots they could also hit the point to navigate.

Comment: here's an example of dot navigation, you can incorporate swipe to navigate as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227985/jquery-mobile-page-indicator-dots/20239664#20239664 Edit: demo with swipe http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L297j/

Comment: @omar: Very useful, thank you. I am still concerned if people will understand that there are pages left or right and if they know how to get there.

Comment: You could create transparent buttons on both sides if the screen to inform user that there's a page after this. I will post an answer later with more details.

Comment: here's an idea http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qgvW3/

Comment: @Omar: Good layout, thanks. We will probably use the pagination dots that you proposed but maybe add the transparent buttons.

Comment: If you need further assistance, let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This sample i wrote for JQM V1.3, indicates current page when swiping.

here is the code

css

```
#circle { width: 28px; height: 28px; border-radius: 35px; font-size: 12px; color: white; line-height: 28px; text-align: center; background: rgba(0, 180, 255, 0.8); margin:0 auto; }
#circleb { width: 25px; height: 25px; border-radius: 35px; font-size: 12px; color: white; line-height: 25px; text-align: center; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); margin:0 auto; }

#pop1, #pop2, #pop3, #pop4, #pop5, #pop6, #pop7, #pop8 { position:fixed; bottom:0px; right: 0%; left: 0%; width: 100%; }
```

the pop1 to pop8 you see above is how many pages you have, so if you have 2 pages then use pop1 and pop2 or if you 15 then pop1 to pop15.

Now considering the screen width of a mobile device, 10 bubbles fit perfect on an iphone. I haven't tried more but on tablets you probably fit more. So consider changing the ccs circle size and set a smaller font size.

Put this inside of your pages

```
  <div data-role="popup" id="pop2" data-theme="a">
  <table width="100%">
  <tr>         
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>1</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circle"><a>2</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>3</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>4</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>5</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>6</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>7</a></div></td>
  <td><div id="circleb"><a>8</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

make sure you change the id="pop(number)" for each page. the above is for page 2 (pop2)
also make a note on the table id="circle" is the active blue, id="circleb" is the black, so change that for each page

and add this javascript in the head of the page

```
 $( '#page1' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event){
  setTimeout(function () {
  $( "#pop1" ).show();
  }, 100); 
  setTimeout(function () {
  $( "#pop1" ).hide();
 }, 1500); 
 });
```

now that code is for page one, so you need to repeat the code for each page like for page two lets say

```
 $( '#page2' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event){
  setTimeout(function () {
  $( "#pop2" ).show();
  }, 100); 
  setTimeout(function () {
  $( "#pop2" ).hide();
 }, 1500); 
 });
```

repeat upto how many pages you have

make sure your data-role="page" has the id's to relate like the above codes

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a" data-dom-cache="true" >
```

and that's it

Comment: Thanks. Check Omar's comments - they contain the best answers. I accept this answer anyway, well designed.