# How can I add swipe page change to bootstrap 3 website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I've made a number of pages for my site [http://lhcrt.org.uk/ltrail/trailindex_page1.html] as a first attempt at a new responsive site. Initially the nav bar was made in Mobirise but the rest added as bootstrap 3 in Pinegrow.

I want to add simple left/right swipe action anywhere on the page  to change to the next page.  I've tried all the ideas I can find on the net such as Hammer.js and while it works in a simple html demo page I'm going mad trying to add it to my working pages. I cant get anything to work but to be honset I dont understand enough detail. Whats the easiest way to do this?
Can someone please help me and a good cause at the same time.

Comment: This is not really a bootstrap question... more of a UI library thing

Answer (score 0):

This is not something bootstrap itself can solve for you, you will want some kind of UI library.

Have a look at [jQuery Mobile Ui](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html) and [Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/touchevents/index).

Also see this SO question:
[How to design swipe page navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403451/how-to-design-swipe-page-navigation)

and this one:
[Using swipe gestures to change pages in multi page jquery mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797331/using-swipe-gestures-to-change-pages-in-multi-page-jquery-mobile-application)

And this little library:
http://demo.dsheiko.com/spn/

Comment: Thanks Tim. I had seen those, I will study some more. I was wondering if there was anything inherent in the Bootstrap framework that prevented jquery mobile from being added on as well.

Comment: @paulmarshall I wouldn't import all the jQuery UI css etc, but a lot of jQuery stuff is modular so you can bring in just the bits you need. Working with jQuery in a mobile environment you may want to have a read about http://touchpunch.furf.com/ as well, but that involves more of the jQuery UI widget junk we bootstrap people try to avoid :)

Comment: The last one by Dsheiko works, just what I wanted. Lightweight and very easy to implement. I hadnt tried it before because it doesnt include the mouse so its harder to test. I still dont understand where I was going wrong with jquery but now I'm not so bothered. I also want to avoid unnecessry stuff.